# How can I get the log from 10am to 13pm every day after 2022/06/01

Tags: git

This command works normally. I can get today's log from 10am to 13pm.

`git log --oneline --since=10am --until=13pm`

But this command works strangely. This shows all my logs without any filtering.

`git log --oneline --since=10am --until=13pm --after=2022-06-01`

Comment: I guess --since and --until options are used with Date not time.

Comment: Do you see commits before 2022-06-01 (or do you not have any before that date)?

Comment: "13pm" is not exactly valid - did you mean "1300 hours" or "1 pm"? In any case, parts you don't fill in with `--since` or `--until` are filled in with "now", so `--since=10am --until=1pm` means those times *today*.

Comment: Meanwhile, `--after` and `--since` *mean the same thing*. I don't think they combine (so `--after=yesterday` would overwrite the `--since` you specified earlier, for instance) but they might combine; but if you want to do complex date filtering, you'll need to do that yourself, either by specifying multiple `git log` commands, or doing one `git log`, reading the date-and-time values, and doing your own post-processing filter.

Comment: What about obtaining the entry logs with several columns, parsing it and filter with your own criteria?

Comment: @torek So I can't get a specific range of time after a specific date?

Comment: @Joe199382 What you describe is not **a** specific range. It's a series of specific ranges. So : no you can't. You'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: What @RomainValeri said: you want "between 10 AM and 1 PM on the 1st" plus "between 10 AM and 1 PM on the 2nd" plus "between 10 AM and 1 PM on the 3rd" plus ....  That's a fairly long list of --since and --until (or --after and --before) options, or a program you write.

Answer (score 2):

`--since` and `--after` are synonymous. The latter one wins, hence, you see all commits since 2022-06-01, not just those from today.

Comment: How can I get the log from 10am to 13pm every day since 2022/06/01?

Comment: As @torek said, you have to grind the data manually. Git can't do such complex date filtering for you.